# Having issues serializing json string to c# object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class that calls a webservice which returns a JSON string which I need to deserialize into a C# object. I was successfully able to do this; however, I came across a scenario that I am not sure exactly the best way to handle. More specifically, the JSON will either return a `List<List<object>>` or just a `List<object>`. I am having a problem when I deserialize if my object is `List<object>` and the JSON is `List<List<object>>`.  In that case, an exception is thrown.

This is class that I am trying to deserialize:

```
    public class WorkOrderJson
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Properties properties { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        public string FeatureType { get; set; }
        public string WorkOrderID { get; set; }
        public string EqEquipNo { get; set; }
    }
```

For the Geometry class the coordinates returned are the issue from above. If the JSON returned is a `List<List<object>>` it serializes fine.

```
    public class Geometry
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> coordinates { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how I am performing deserialization:

```
    WorkOrderJson workOrderJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<WorkOrderJson>>(responseString);
```

where `responseString` is the JSON string returned from web service. Hope this makes sense. If anybody has come across a similar issue, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is an example for `List<List<object>>` where `coordinates` is the list:

```
[
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "FeatureType": "WORKORDER",
            "WorkOrderID": "AMO172-2015-107",
            "EqEquipNo": "AC-LIN-001"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -111.00041804208979,
                    33.0002148138019
                ],
                [
                    -111.00027869450028,
                    33.000143209356054
                ]
            ]
        },
        "symbology": {
            "color": "#990000",
            "lineWidth": "8"
        }
    }
]
```

Here is an example for `List<object>`:

```
[
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "FeatureType": "WORKORDER",
            "WorkOrderID": "AMO172-2015-115",
            "EqEquipNo": "AC-LIN-001"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -111.00041804208979,
                33.0002148138019
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: This tool is nice just paste your json in there. http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @vikingben Yes i used that to create the object for the above json. However i could be getting either message above and the class generated is a list(coordinate) for second post and list(list(coordinate)) for the first post

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone that cares changing the Geometry Class to the following solved my problem:

```
public class Geometry
{
        public string type { get; set; }
        public object coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Just changed list to object. Then at runtime i can check whether the object is list of lists or just a list and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom [JavaScriptConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) and register it with your JavaScriptSerializer.

You would then deserialize like this:

```
var converter = new JavaScriptSerializer();
converter.RegisterConverters(new List<JavaScriptConverter>() {new GeometryConverter()});
var workOrderJson = converter.Deserialize<List<WorkOrderJson>>(response);
```

This converter would work:

```
public class GeometryConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new List<Type>(new Type[] {typeof(Geometry)}); }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        Geometry geometry = obj as Geometry;

        if (geometry != null)
        {
            // Create the representation
            var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            if (geometry.coordinates.Count == 1)
            {
                result.Add("type", "Point");
                result.Add("coordinates", geometry.coordinates[0]);
            }
            else if (geometry.coordinates.Count > 1)
            {
                result.Add("type", "LineString");
                result.Add("coordinates", geometry.coordinates);
            }
            return result;
        }

        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");

        Geometry geometry = null;
        if (type == typeof(Geometry))
        {
            geometry = new Geometry();
            geometry.type = (string)dictionary["type"];
            geometry.coordinates = new List<List<double>>();
            if ( geometry.type == "Point")
            {
                ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList)dictionary["coordinates"];
                geometry.coordinates.Add(ConvertCoordinates(arrayList));
            }
            else if (geometry.type == "LineString")
            {
                geometry.type = "LineString";
                ArrayList coordinatesList = (ArrayList)dictionary["coordinates"];
                foreach (ArrayList arrayList in coordinatesList)
                {
                    geometry.coordinates.Add(ConvertCoordinates(arrayList));
                }
            }
        }
        return geometry;
    }

    private List<double> ConvertCoordinates(ArrayList coordinates)
    {
        var list = new List<double>();
        foreach (var coordinate in coordinates)
        {
            list.Add((double)System.Convert.ToDouble(coordinate));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like a great solution. My solution is already working so not gonna mess with it but this is much better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand and you are trying to deserialize a `List<List<a>>` as a `List<a>`, it *should* error. You're telling it to deserialize it into something other than what it was before serialization. I would recommend either propagating some indication of which it is along with the string so you can check and deserialize as that type, or wrap the deserialization attempts and `try` one first, then the other if it fails.

**Edit per update**

```
public class WorkOrderJson<T>
{
    public Geometry<T> geometry { get; set; }

    public WorkOrderJson<List<T>> Promote()
    {
        var temp = new WorkOrderJson<List<T>>();
        temp.geometry = geometry.Promote();
        return temp;
    }
}
public class Geometry<T>
{
    public T coordinates { get; set; }

    public Geometry<List<T>> Promote()
    {
        var temp = new Geometry<List<T>>();
        temp.coordinates = new List<T>(){ coordinates };
        return temp;
    }
}

public List<WorkOrder<List<List<double>>>> Deserialize(string x)
{
    try
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<WorkOrderJson<List<List<double>>>>>(x);
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<WorkOrderJson<List<double>>>>(x).Select(workOrder => workOrder.Promote());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i agree and it should fail but the problem is that the json return string is "coordinates" for both list(list(object)) and list(object) so how would i create the Geometry class when i don't know if return is list(list(object)) or list(object). Question is how to handle both?

Comment: @Maxqueue I understand better with your update what the issue is. Looks like you found a resolution, but an alternative would be to parameterize `WorkOrder` (and `Geometry`) so it would be `WorkOrder<List<List<double>>>` or `WorkOrder<List<double>>`. `try` to deserialize as the first one, and if that fails deserialize as the second one. You would need to "promote" the `List<double>` case to `List<List<double>>` when returning (a list of one element), though, so they are the same type.

Comment: But then you would have two variables with same name.

Comment: @Maxqueue I updated the answer with an example of what I'm proposing. It's not pretty and whether it's worth it depends on your use case. But having a bare `object` floating around and possibly having to switch on whether it's a `List` or a `List<List>` everywhere isn't really appealing either.